# Nginx refused by database

Tags: php, docker, nginx, raspberry-pi

I'm trying to run a website server on a raspberry pi and I'm running into the following error in the log for nginx:

[error] 20#20: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: , server: , request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://172.24.0.2:80/favicon.ico", host: "mywebsite.com", referrer: "https://mywebsite.com/"

172.24.0.2 is the internal IP address of db container.

My config file looks like:

```
server{
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name mywebsite.com;  

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://wordpress:80/;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    }
    
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/wolfsciences.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/wolfsciences.com/privkey.pem;
}
```

And the yaml file is:

```
version: "3.7"
services:

  db: 
    build: ./db
    container_name: db
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    volumes:
      - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
    environment: 
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
      MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
      MYSQL_USER: wordpress
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: password
    networks:
      website_network:
        aliases: 
          - wordpress
  
  wordpress:
    build: .
    container_name: wordpress
    ports:
      - "80"
    networks:
      website_network:
        aliases: 
          - wordpress
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wordpress
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: password
      WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: wordpress

  nginx:
    build: ./nginx
    container_name: nginx
    ports:
      - "443:443"
      - "80"
    networks:
      website_network:
        aliases:
          - nginx-proxy
      
networks:
  website_network: 
    name: website_network

volumes:
  db_data:
    driver: local
    name: db_data
```

I'm at such a loss I don't even know where to begin.

I haven't even be able to figure out where to start. I'm knew to docker containers so I don't know how to get them to talk. I've been following a tutorial, and got the website to work for a bit, but now it just loads a blank screen.

Comment: Is the Wordpress application configured to listen on port 80, or somewhere else?  Docker can't reconfigure this port number on its own if the application uses something different.  The Docker-level networking setup seems correct (and also unnecessary; consider deleting all of the `networks:` blocks in the whole file).

Answer (score 0):

You told nginx that the database server, which isn't listening of port 80, should be contacted when trying to reach the wordpress container:

> My config file looks like:
>
> ```
>     location / {
>         proxy_pass http://wordpress:80/;
>         proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
>     }
> ```
>
> And the yaml file is:
>
> ```yaml
> ...
>   db: 
>     ...
>     networks:
>       website_network:
>         aliases: 
>           - wordpress
> ```

To resolve this, delete all of the network aliases in the compose file, you aren't using them correctly and they are only breaking things. You can depend on the default alias of the service name (in this case `db` to reach the db container).

The resulting compose file can be simplified to:

```yaml
version: "3.7"
services:

  db: 
    build: ./db
    container_name: db
    ports:
      - "3306:3306" # this is likely not needed
    volumes:
      - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
    environment: 
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
      MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
      MYSQL_USER: wordpress
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: password
  
  wordpress:
    build: .
    container_name: wordpress
    ports:
      - "80" # this is only needed for debugging
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wordpress
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: password
      WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: wordpress

  nginx:
    build: ./nginx
    container_name: nginx
    ports:
      - "443:443"
      - "80"

volumes:
  db_data:
    driver: local
    name: db_data
```

The result is that nginx will try connecting to the wordpress container rather than your database container. Whether that connection works depends on your wordpress image listening on port 80. The upstream wordpress image does, but yours is built from a different Dockerfile.

Comment: Thanks for the help but didn't seem to fix something, or maybe I'm not understanding. I tried a few iterations where I either flat out deleted all the networks, changed them around, changed stuff in the config file etc and nothing worked. Hate to ask, but can you be more specific?